# Use table valued function with entity framework code first

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to execute a table valued function and get a list of entities .

```
[DbFunction("APIDBContext", "GetMyEntities")]
public virtual IQueryable<MyEntity> GetMyEntities(Nullable<int> userId)
            {
      return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<MyEntity>(string.Format("[{0}].{1}", GetType().Name,
                        "[GetMyEntities](@userId)"), userIdParameter).AsQueryable();

    }
```

Seems like it I need to have same names for the columns i'm returning from the database even though I have specified column mappings in the model builder.

I'm getting the excception

`nvalid column name 'MyColumn'`

But I have mapped this column in the model builder ,
`Property(e => e.MyColumn).HasColumnName("My_Column");`

Is this not supported yet in entity framework code first ?